# In Javascript, can every function be considered a constructor of a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I don't see any syntactic difference between an ordinary function, and one which behaves like a constructor for a class. So are they the same?

Does this mean that every single function we define has a property named 'prototype' by default?

Comment: Javascript hasn't got classes per say.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every function has a property named `prototype` by default. The "construction" functionality is provided by the [[Construct]] internal property(invoked by `new F()`), which is set for every created function(see http://es5.github.io/#x13.2 - creating function objects, p18)

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JS have default property prototype, so to your question - yes.

But its very confusing to use it as a class structure within your code. I'd suggest you to check  [TypeScript language](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Class hierarchy is similar to C#'s and compiler is compiling TypeScript code to confusing JavaScript for you :-)